# ChromeDriver prevent detection

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

From various other questions here on SO etc. it is clear that one of the main reasons for websites being able to detect Selenium/ChromeDriver is being used, is the javascript property

```
document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_
```

Is there anyway to prevent this property being created (that does not involve a custom build of ChromeDriver)? Like for example disabling this cache somehow? It would really be preferrable without a custom build. Perhaps with a configuration option of randomizing the property name.

Or would it be possible to somehow through the driver something like this:

```
delete document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_;
```

Initial testing seems to indicate that this does not work. Perhaps because a new cache is created just after executing this script, or similar.

Comment: Turns out that the javascript can be edited (with care) directly in the chromedriver executable. Unfortunately that didn't prevent the detection in my case though.

Comment: I'm curious if you discovered the mechanism they were using to detect chromedriver. I have also noticed chromedriver is enabling a "Chrome Automation Extension", not sure if that has any relevance.

Comment: I did not find the mechanism. The javascript in question is heavily obfuscated, and really complicated. For now I have gone with JBrowserDriver instead.